# Draw a line (path) with pure CSS from one point to another

Tags: html, css

I have an image animating in this path below and would like the path to be visible.

CSS:

```
div {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:Player1;
    -webkit-animation-duration:100s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1);
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:5;
    -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running
}

@-webkit-keyframes Player1 {
0% {
    background:red;
    left:20px;
    top:20px
}

25% {
    background:#ff0;
    left:800px;
    top:200px
}

50% {
    background:blue;
    left:950px;
    top:500px
}

75% {
    background:green;
    left:0;
    top:800px
}

100% {
    background:red;
    left:0;
    top:0
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/wh8LM/)

Is it possible to have a line linking them with only CSS code? And if not, would you please help me with the code?

Comment: Can you show this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: you could animate a rotated div in its width and set its transform origin to a corner

Comment: @misterManSam sorry I don't know how jsfiddle work but I updated my code with my whole source code hope it helps?

Comment: you can use svg element to draw that line.

Comment: @LorDex can i change my left:800px;
    top:200px to a x and y-axis instead? that the code look like 75% {
    background:green;
    y=0;
    x=8? because svg use x and y coordinates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is obviously what SVG (Structured Vector Graphics) are for.

```
<svg>
    <polyline points="20,20 800,200 950,500 0,800 0,0"></polyline>    
</svg>
```

[Working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/wh8LM/1/).

[Or at a usable speed here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/wh8LM/3/).

Answer (score 2):

You can animate the start point of a line in svg (also reversed) "stroke-dashoffset" like this example in codepen

```
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/Yudo/full/OaEWXK

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the the angle and distance between points and use CSS Transforms to push the line where you want it.  Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47Gf7/). It's a little crude, but I think you'll get the idea.

```
var startPoint=[200,200], 
    endPoint=[300,300],
    rise=endPoint[1]-startPoint[1],
    run=endPoint[0]-startPoint[0],
    slope=rise/run,
    DEGREES=57.2957795,
    width=Math.sqrt((rise*rise)+(run*run));
var line=document.getElementById('line');
line.style.top=startPoint[0]+'px';
line.style.left=startPoint[1]+'px';
line.style.width=width+"px";
line.style.transform= "rotate("+(Math.atan(slope)*DEGREES)+"deg)";
line.style.transformOrigin= "0 0";
```