# Draw line with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142099/draw-a-line-path-with-pure-css-from-one-point-to-another), I wrote this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/ztnr9td4/), where I want to add two points. The problem might be that the points lie inside a hexagon.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="hexagon">
  <span>
    <div id="dot_spd"></div>
      <svg>
        <polyline id="spd_att" points="34,0 93,-43"></polyline>    
      </svg>
    <div id="dot_att"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

If you look carefully in the output, you will see that there is a tiny line displayed, like the origin (x=0, y=0), blocks the line from been displayed properly!

What am I missing?

---

1. If I swap the points, nothing happens.
2. ***Somehow, I have to move the `<svg>` inside the hexagon area.***

Comment: `<div>` inside `<span>`? (Removing SPAN: http://jsfiddle.net/ztnr9td4/1/)

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected output is supposed to look like? Which line do you mean? I can see four green lines around the hexagon.

Comment: Doesn't `-43` draw the line out of the svg view box?

Comment: @Terry that's what I am talking about!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! However, the points will have coordinates of such nature. How to deal with them? Xufox, not sure what do you mean. You have two red points. I want them to get connected by a line.

Comment: @gsamaras removing the SPAN I get a prettynice hexy

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that should be an issue, since if I remove the `<span>`, I won't get a hexagon and I use `<div>`, in order to "create" the points. If I move the div tags outside of the span tags, the dots won't appear.

Comment: You will then have to reposition your SVG, and make sure you are drawing WITHIN the view box...? That means positioning your SVG absolutely within the hexagon of course.

Comment: Roko, if I do this, I am getting something like an envelope. Moreover the points are gone. @Terry yes that's it. Can you help on how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.... You want a line?

```js
function placeDiv(id, x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.getElementById(id);
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
  d.style.top = y_pos+'px';
}

placeDiv("dot_spd", 34, 0);
placeDiv("dot_att", 93, -43);
```

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 115.47px;
  background-color: #1d2125;
  margin: 57.74px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  border-left: solid 5px #494949;
  border-right: solid 5px #494949;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 141.42px;
  height: 141.42px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 24.2893px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.hexagon:before {
  top: -70.7107px;
  border-top: solid 7.0711px #494949;
  border-right: solid 7.0711px #494949;
}

.hexagon:after {
  bottom: -70.7107px;
  border-bottom: solid 7.0711px #494949;
  border-left: solid 7.0711px #494949;
}

/*cover up extra shadows*/
.hexagon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:2.8867513459481287px;
  left: 0;
  width:190px;
  height:109.6966px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}

/* dot */
#dot_spd, #dot_att, #dot_tec,
#dot_str, #dot_def, #dot_pow{
 color: #9C1E1E;
 height: 1px;
 width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

/* line from dot to dot */
polyline {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke: #9C1E1E;
}
svg {
    overflow:visible;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">
  <span>
    <div id="dot_spd"></div>
      <svg>
        <polyline id="spd_att" points="34,0 93,-43"></polyline>  
      </svg>
 <div id="dot_att"></div>
  </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ztnr9td4/2/ I presume that's what you want :) Just add `overflow:visible;`

Comment: Well yes. If you check my fiddle you will see that my code is almost the same as yours. The problem is that my svg is not positioned nicely, which makes the line not to display. Can you check the fiddle and work on that? It seems that you know what you are up to!! :)

Comment: About your edit: I am getting a line above the hexagon (remember that the goal is to connect the two points!). Also the hexagon is altered a lot and the points are not visible anymore... :/

Comment: Yeah I'll try to write something proper :) Tried mashing things together...Clearly not a good idea ;)

Comment: You could try modifying my fiddle Olavi! :D

Comment: Integers like the ones I have in my example: 34,0 and 93,-43 (on format x, y).

Comment: @gsamaras You can try it now, however... I would strictly suggest against using css to draw things, especially hexagons. Try looking at the same thing in firefox/IE.

Comment: 500 is too much, you can use this to get the same effect: `z-index:3;`. The answer is perfect. Well, if you have any resource to make this with another way, please share it.

Comment: @gsamaras sorry for all the edits, I should note that ONLY overflow:visible is needed, your only problem is that you are going to the negative area(the polyline starts at y cord 0, which is the edge, the svg you created is actually 190x150 so that's not the problem )